# Date comparison in MongoDb and Java

Tags: java, mongodb, date, extjs

I have to compare an EQUAL comparison between dates from UI and DB. Its working with below code

ExtJs Code :-

```
        xtype: 'datefield'
        ,fieldLabel:'By Date'
        ,name: 'byDate'
        ,format: 'd-m-Y'
        ,flex:1
```

and Code in Java is :-

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("bookingtime").regex(byDate, "i"));
```

The format `d-m-Y` gives me date in format `27-11-2016` or `15-10-2016`. If the date in DB is as same as in date from UI ,like `27-11-2016` etc, this works like a charm.

But the problems arises when I select date in UI as `07-01-2016` which becomes `7-1-2016` in java. Since date in DB is in format `07-01-2016` and it fails the match and I get nothing.

Could you please help.

Comment: So if I understand well, your dates in the DB are always stored with the dd-mm-YYYY format. Therefore you should always compare two things that are equals : you should reformat 7-1-2016 to be of format dd-mm-YYYY

Comment: Dates in DB are stored in `dd-mm.YYYY-hh.MM.ss` that's why I am comparing Dates with regex and I know that I have to format my date from `7-1-2016` to `07-01-2016`. But is there any other way to do the same with mongodbTemplates or get `07-01-2016` directly from UI?

Comment: Using regex would cause performance issues and in the end it might be not working ad expected. I strongly advice you to go with the format solution